# Design & Custom Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

have a longer question than usual.

I am attempting to make a card game and I am confused as to whether I am designing it awfully.

The player's hand consists of 10 cards, each of which is a button and 4 labels that indicate the stats of the card.

What I had in mind was creating an array of objects that have these UILabel and button properties. For example in a "Card" class I would have...

```
@IBOutlet var cardName: UILabel
@IBOutlet var cardStat1: UILabel
@IBOutlet var cardStat2: UILabel
@IBOutlet var cardStat3: UILabel
@IBOutlet var cardStat4: UILabel
```

I would then have an array that contains ten objects of this Card class. This is my design portion of my question.

---

My View Controller question is like I mentioned above - I have a Card class but I am having trouble connecting outlets to it. It inherits from UIViewController but I get the error...

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'

...even though I call

```
super.init()
```

---

Feel free to aid me with any portion of my issues, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> This is my design portion of my question.

Having 10 view controllers, one for each card, sounds like a solution that's far more complicated than it needs to be. I think you'd be better off with something like a collection view, with one collection view cell for each card. You'd also need some kind of data model for storing the information about each card -- an array of dictionaries, for example, or an array of your Card objects (but not derived from UIViewController).

> I get the error...

The designated initializers for UIViewController are `-initWithNibName:bundle:` and `-initWithCoder:`. There's an `-init` method defined, but it sounds like Swift wants you to call a designated initializer, and that's not `-init`.

Comment: Maybe I need to look up the documentation on initWithNibName:bundle: because I'm not sure what to fill in for those arguments.